# Snapping in QGIS

Tags: qgis, topology, snapping

I have a Layer and I have lines as if they were the sidewalks, so for every street I have two lines.
The problem is that some of the lines are not joined, how could I join them?

[image]

Comment: Please research first before posting questions. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/46853/how-does-snapping-in-qgis-work?r=SearchResults

Comment: I did that before, But didn't work.
I put Default snap mode to Vertex. Snapping tolerance 15,00000 pixels and search radius for vertex edits also 15,00000 pixels

Comment: [See here for more info](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/278345/unable-to-snap-vertices-and-segment-in-qgis-3-0) Another remark: do you really want each segment to be an own feature? Perhaps you should consider joining them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open "QGIS with Grass", open the "Toolbox" under the "Processing" menu. Under "Processing Toolbox" searc type "Clean". There is a tool from Grass that should help you.

[image]

More details about the tool are available [here](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/v.clean.html).

Comment: I tried that, but the result is a error. I am going to explain:
I have a line, with this line, I create 2 offset, after that in the above image I show you these 2 offset, but for example when I try what you told, I put one offset and then in tool I put just "snap". but it doesn't wrong.

Comment: Use the snap tool.

Comment: Yes, I did that. I put my "offset" in layer to dean, afterthat in "Input feature type" I selected all options (lines, points,...) if I change that and I put just one, also it doesn't work.  And afterthat I put in "cleaning tool" -> "snap", and finally in "v.in.ogr snap torelance" I put 3,00000.
I click in "run" but the program show me an error: ERROR 1: Wrong field type for fid. 
ERROR: Unable to create colun <fid>